Visual Studio cannot locate MASM's include and lib
i wanted to include Windows GUI in my code so i include all lib in picture.
enter image description here
enter image description here
But even though i downloaded MASM both in Visual Studio 2022 SDK 10.0 and http://www.masm32.com/download.htm, add include directories in Configuration Properties but no hope. Also tried run in VSCode through DOSBox but still have same error.
enter image description here
